# Counting multiple fields of a document in each other document against different fields in the same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have millions of documents like this :

```
{
  "anId" : "xxxxx-yyyyy-zzzzzz"
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2" : [
       {"field1": "value2", ...}
    ]
}
```

I first $match equality on anId.
Then my goal is to count on field1 and field2.field1 for each document in any other document so that:

```
field1 -> field1
field1 -> field2.field1
field2.field1 -> field1
```

And finally I want the result being like:

```
{"field1" : "value1", countings : 10}
{"field1" : "value2", countings : 5}
```

I'm trying with lookups but they are tremendously slow, even though foreignField's are indexed:

lookup1:

```
{
  from: 'same_collection',
  localField: 'field1',
  foreignField: 'field1',
  as: 'field1_field1'
}
```

lookup2:

```
{
  from: 'same_collection',
  localField: 'field1',
  foreignField: 'field2.field1',
  as: 'field1_field2'
}
```

lookup3:

```
{
  from: 'same_collection',
  localField: 'field2.field1',
  foreignField: 'field1',
  as: 'field2_field1'
}
```

Since I'm getting 3 lists, I'm concatenating them into one:
project1:

```
{
  field1 : 1,
  concats : 
    {$concatArrays : 
      [{$ifNull: ['$field1_field1', []]},
       {$ifNull: ['$field1_field2', []]},
       {$ifNull: ['$field2_field1', []]}]
    }
}
```

Then I filter inside them, to ensure that each document takes concats which are not counted from the same looked up document (_id != $id), plus other filterings:
project2:

```
{
  field1:1,
  concats: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$concats",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $and :[
                 {$eq: ["$$item.user_id", "23" ]},
                 {$ne: ["$$item._id","$_id"]},
                 {$eq: [{$type:'$$item.deleted'},"missing"]}
                 ]
               }
            }
         }
}
```

and then projecting finally:
project3:

```
{
  _id : 0,
  field1:1,
  countings : {$size : "$concats"}
}
```

So, the collection has 24M docs. I'm limiting the query to 50K docs, because it times out otherwise. This means that, even though the lookups have 50K localFields to lookup from, the foreignField's to lookup to are anyway 23M (am I right?).
I also tried with specialized lookups with let and pipeline, but they're even slower.

Execution stats (50K):

```
lookup1:
nReturned: 50000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 5481 }

lookup2:
 nReturned: 50000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 10245 }

lookup3:
nReturned: 50000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 16911 }

project1:
 nReturned: 50000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 16911 }

project2:
 nReturned: 50000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 16911 }

project3:
nReturned: 50000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 16913 } ]

Total:
 nReturned: 50000,
             executionTimeMillis: 16931,
             totalKeysExamined: 50000,
             totalDocsExamined: 50000
```

Execution stats (100k):

```
lookup1:
nReturned: 100000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 16688 }

lookup2:
nReturned: 100000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27461 }

lookup3:
nReturned: 100000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 35955 }

project1:
nReturned: 100000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 35955 }

project2:
 nReturned: 100000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 35963 }

project3:
nReturned: 100000,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 35965 } ]

total:
nReturned: 100000,
             executionTimeMillis: 35990,
             totalKeysExamined: 100000,
             totalDocsExamined: 100000
```

Is there any other way to achieve this faster?

Comment: So you `$match` on `anId`.  But when you turn around and requery for any `field2.field2 = field`, it does not have to `$match` the `anId` that it might find?  Also, out of 24M docs, for a given `anId` how many total countings might you expect?  10? 10000? 1M?

Comment: Actually, the best thing I'd need to do is that when I lookup I'd need it to be done with equality on field user_id and deleted false. Right now, it is looking up to the entire collection and after that I filter for user_id and deleted in the latest projection. I tried with let and pipeline but it went timeout. Also to answer your question,  in this case, by filtering by anId I start with 2M docs, limiting thereafter at 50k. I expect finally to have 50k results, each of which has field1 and its countings

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day you're performing 3 lookups for 50k documents, those are 150k queries ( each performing an index scan). This means there's not much you can do to improve performance, especially considering hard limitations like x amount of readers per db.

The one thing that could potentially improve the run time is that these 3 `$lookup` could be ran in parallel instead of one after the other as there is some overhead in running them one after the other, this could be done using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/):

```
{
    $facet: {
        field1_field1: [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'same_collection',
                    localField: 'field1',
                    foreignField: 'field1',
                    as: 'field1_field1',
                },
            },
        ],
        field1_field2: [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'same_collection',
                    localField: 'field1',
                    foreignField: 'field2.field1',
                    as: 'field1_field2',
                },
            },
        ],
        field2_field1: [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'same_collection',
                    localField: 'field2.field1',
                    foreignField: 'field1',
                    as: 'field2_field1',
                },

            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Now this is still an incredible work load burst for the db to handle so this might not improve performance by a lot, it depends how loaded your server is, but it does give the potential to scale up. Also worth noting that you'll need to change your `$concatArrays` slightly as the structure will be different.

I will also mention other factors to consider that only you can know, for example if any of your stages exceed the `100mb` memory limit and you use the `allowDiskUse` flag, this means Mongo is writing and reading results to/from the disk. If that's the case I would consider moving the "lookups" to queries in code ( under the presumption that the network between the two servers is fast as this is also a consideration for such move ). There are quite a few hardware limitations to think about, I believe this is where you could actually get a meaningful performance boost.